# symfony: stConfig::set('name', 'value') not working

Tags: dynamic, configuration, symfony-1.4

I have the following configuration in `defaults.yml`:

`poll_votes:

     type:                         string

     value:                        ''

     name:                         'Votes'

          description:                  ''

          editable:                     true

          system:                       false

          nullable:                     false`

`stConfig::get('poll_votes');` will return the correct value (which can be updated in the backend), but the value is not updated when calling `stConfig::set('poll_votes', 'option1: 1 vote');`

How can I set this values dynamically? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

stConfig? IIRC wasn't it sfConfig in Symfony 1?

Unless you are asking to change the contents of defaults.yml itself.

Comment: Wanted to add this as clarification rather than answer to the question, don't know how.

Comment: Thanks. I am also not sure about this. stConfig::get('name') returns the correct value, even after it has been modified in the backend. I am not asking to change the defaults.yml file itself, but the stored configuration values.

Comment: Do you want to change the value so that another function would use a different value? Otherwise why would you want to set it, sfConfig is meant for setting constants. [API page on sfConfig](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfConfig) does point to having set function. Try to use sfConfig, instead of stConfig.

Comment: I am using ViMP professional, and the backend code is protected with SourceGuardian. I needed a fast way to add a configuration variable that could be later modified in the application. If sfConfig does not work, I might try to modify the database entries directly.

Comment: Remember that `sfConfig::set()` will change the value only for the duration of the script. The new value will be lost once the script is invoked again. The config values are not meant to be changed dynamically and this is not a good practice to do so. Maybe you could use the session or some other container within the sfContext. You could also use the database if you need to persist the new values.

Comment: Even if you set the correct variable in sfConfig, the new variable will only last until PHP process has ended. You would have to reset it on every request. So you can either set the variable as a database entry or in user's session(sfAction->getUser()->setAttribute('name','anyvalue')).

Comment: Thank you both. Editing the database entries directly (the config table) was the solution.